# Stress recovery in town without abbey or tavern

Tags: darkest-dungeon

I saw that my Heroes also recover from stress every week in town when they are doing nothing (no misssion and not in tavern or abby), but only very slow. How much do they recover in this way every week? Is this recovery a fixed number/percentage or random or does it depend on class, quirks/perks and actual stresslevel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is always 5 units of stress healed, a pitiful amount compared to the abbey/tavern or even stress healing while camping. Sometimes though - I'm unsure if it's because of an affliction or affect gained from questing or if it's just they are stagnant for too long - they will actually start to *gain* stress instead. They will notify you with a little something like "I'm getting restless!"

Sidenote: For stress I honestly just try to make my camping skills all stress related and have healers in the party (generally just self healers but that's up to you, I love how diverse you can make parties in this game and still be able to complete it).

EDIT: Wanted to confirm, here's a link: http://darkestdungeon.gamepedia.com/Stress

Comment: The Jester is also able to heal stress while in combat.  It might not seem like much but can be surprisingly effective.

Comment: Same with the houndmaster, and the abomination can self heal stress very efficiently (though at the cost of party stress). My current favorite party is 1st Helion, 2nd abomination, 3rd Bounty Hunter (though I like Jester here as well, just squisher), 4th houndmaster.

Comment: With the newest versions of the game there are now Districts/passive upgrades you can build in the Hamlet. One of these is, I believe, a Puppet Theater which adds another 10 passive stress healed per week for those remaining in the Hamlet during your mission. That is a total of 15 per week which isn't too shabby if you have enough heroes that they take 3-5 weeks off between missions.